# lambda with condition x: 1/x if x!= 0 not work

Tags: python, manim

I want to draw an inverse proportional function with GraphScene, everything works, However when I set condition of `x != 0`, a SyntaxError pops:

```
f11 = self.get_graph(lambda x: 1/x if x!= 0)

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

the error indicates the last parenthesis

I searched a lot, the `lambda x: 1/x if x!= 0` should be a correct python syntax, don't know why it not work! thanks for any help.

Comment: "should be a correct Python syntax" -- what specific thing that you read leads you to believe that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `else` telling what the lambda should evaluate to when `x==0`, and suddenly you have valid syntax:

```
lambda x: 1/x if x != 0 else 0
```

---

This syntax construct was added in [PEP-308](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/), which was [adopted in Python 2.5](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-308.html). From the PEP, the grammar changes are described as follows:

```
test: or_test ['if' or_test 'else' test] | lambdef
or_test: and_test ('or' and_test)*
...
testlist_safe: or_test [(',' or_test)+ [',']]
...
gen_for: 'for' exprlist 'in' or_test [gen_iter]
```

As you can see, `else` is mandatory; there's no way to have a `test` without *both* an `if` and an `else`.

Answer (score 3):

Graphs are created using bezier curves, bezier curves cannot be discontinuous, therefore, you must create multiple graphs for each domain you want to use.

```py
class AddingDomains(GraphScene):
    CONFIG = {
        "y_max" : 5,
        "y_min" : -5,
        "x_max" : 6,
        "x_min" : -6,
        "graph_origin": ORIGIN,
    }
    def construct(self):
        self.setup_axes()
        graph_left = self.get_graph(lambda x : 1/x,  
                                    color = GREEN,
                                    x_min = self.x_min, 
                                    x_max = 1/self.y_min
                                    )
        graph_right = self.get_graph(lambda x : 1/x,  
                                    color = GREEN,
                                    x_min = 1/self.y_max, 
                                    x_max = self.x_max
                                    )
        graph=VGroup(graph_left,graph_right)
        self.play(
            ShowCreation(graph),
            run_time = 2,
            rate_func= double_smooth
        )
        self.wait()
```

Or

```py
class AddingDomains2(GraphScene):
    CONFIG = {
        "y_max" : 5,
        "y_min" : -5,
        "x_max" : 6,
        "x_min" : -6,
        "graph_origin": ORIGIN,
    }
    def construct(self):
        self.setup_axes()
        graph_left = self.get_graph(lambda x : 1/x,  
                                    color = GREEN,
                                    x_min = self.x_min, 
                                    x_max = 1/self.y_min
                                    )
        graph_right = self.get_graph(lambda x : 1/x,  
                                    color = GREEN,
                                    x_min = 1/self.y_max, 
                                    x_max = self.x_max
                                    )
        graph=VMobject(color=RED)
        graph.append_points(graph_left.points)
        graph.append_points(graph_right.points)
        self.play(
            ShowCreation(graph),
            run_time = 2,
            rate_func= double_smooth
        )
        self.wait()
```

Returns:
[image]
More information in *manimlib/mobject/types/vectorized_mobject.py* and *manimlib/mobject/functions.py*.

Comment: Yes, because even if we use Charles Duffy's answer, the graph will not be displayed correctly.

Comment: To be sure; I treated this as a Python question, not a `manim` question. I think there's value to having a answers addressing it both ways; between the two, we cover both the OP's misunderstandings about Python syntax, and their misunderstandings about `manim`.

Comment: I think the same.

Comment: @TheoremOfBeethoven, this answer helps, but I have to choose Charles's as answer because the title, thank you!

Comment: I think it's the right answer, and as Charles said before, my answer is relative only to manim